# Center align nav item

Tags: css, wordpress, uinavigationbar

UPDATE: I've been able to target the code required to make the changes I need. However, i now need to figure out how to only make a section of this div, transparent.

For example, the nav bar is 750 pixels wide. I need to make the first 75 pixels transparent.I know I need to use this code:

```
opacity: 0|initial|inherit;
```

However, how do I only apply that code to a section (75px) within the 750 pixel div? This is the ID and classes that I need to target.

```
#mega_main_menu.primary > .menu_holder > .mmm_fullwidth_container {
background-image: url('http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Nav-     Bar.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

website: www.visualicreative.com

Thank you kindly,

Visual i

Comment: Can't get on your website, but vertical alignment can be achieved by setting the log to be display: inline-block; Then add a line-height:<containerheight>;

Answer (score 0):

As for the logo, set either a margin-top in the menus div or a negative margin-top in the logos, either way, you didn't post complete code so its difficult to give any more help than that.

Answer (score 0):

`transparent` is not a color, but a value of opacity. You will want to use the `opacity` property, instead. Further, in order to set vertical alignment, you can either use the `vertical-align` property after setting your element to `display: table;` or `display: table-cell;`, or you can set the logo to `display: inline-block;` and then set `line-height: X;` where **X** is the height of your container.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I cannot make any of your suggested edits. 

I tried changing the:

    background-color: opacity;

and it said it was invalid. Do I need to input it a different way?

Lastly, I couldn't find the exact #ID you wanted me to target in order to change the display type to your proposed suggestions. Could you please assist me there?

Sorry, I am a very new programmer.

Comment: @Jeffrey9896 You misunderstand; `opacity` is a property, not a value. You would type `opacity: 0.5;` to achieve 50% opacity, or `opacity: 1;` to make it completely opaque. Visit [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) for more in-depth resources on HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I understand what you're saying now. Unfortunately it's still inheriting the native menu bar when I insert the opacity level in the specific cell for: #mega_main_menu .nav_logo .logo_link img { 


Do I need to insert it under the general navigation ID instead? Please visit this page for a reference: http://visualicreative.com/products/corporate/services/

Comment: @Jeffrey9896 In order to help more specifically with regard to your problem, we will need more code (instead of you linking to your website) in the future :-)

Comment: Understood. If you could tell me what code you need, I'll be sure to get it to you. Unfortunately I'm still unable to figure out this problem. Once I do, it will be HUGE!

Thanks for helping me through this.

Comment: @Jeffrey9896 A good starting point is to try and replicate your problem in a sandbox website like JSFiddle or JSBin; that way you can share with other people your code *and* a visual representation of what it looks like, and people can clearly iterate over each other to try and make adjustments.

Comment: I've been able to get more code for you. I posted it in my original post above. Hopefully you can assist me through this problem. Thank you in advance!